# Understanding a disk corruption/corrupt file header issue

Tags: hard-drive, file-corruption

Have a Western Digital Black 3TB SATA drive that's been swapped into a new Windows 7 Pro machine; disk was originally formatted with NTFS and was detected/mounted by the new OS/machine without issues.

This disk contains audio recordings (.wav files, plus Reaper project files, .peaks files, etc.) in a couple of top-level folders for each year.

Roughly around the time I swapped this drive into the new tower in January, project files from the 2016 folder contain .WAV files with invalid/corrupt headers.  The Reaper project loads ok, but the wav files fail to load properly.  I attempted to open them up in Audacity and Windows Media Player, but the same thing has happened: the file cannot be opened or is "not recognized" as a file that the application can open.

What I find strange is that how the wav files themselves are selectively corrupted, but the project folders or the Reaper project files are not.  The disk is reported as healthy with S.M.A.R.T Monitor (freeware tool) and while S.M.A.R.T. isn't everything, I'm confused as to why just that folder, and just the wav files are corrupted.

I've had many failed drives before, and when the seek times start to go, you notice the lag; or there are audible clicks, grinding sounds, etc. with an unhappy disk.

The wave files are huge (several GB each), so I can't see a write-cache/power failure issue being the cause.

Also, newer project folders from this year are fine.

These files have not been accessed by myself since roughly around a week after the project was created and the wav files were recorded/written to disk and a mixdown to MP3 was completed.  For example, a recording project from June of last year that won't open has a date modified of around the same time.

I just don't understand how (presumably) a physical disk move to a new tower would cause selective header corruption in the wave files.

Comment: No actual read errors, just changed files? Any old backups to compare to the corrupted versions? May show if it's a few corrupted sectors, or if the wav format was somehow corrupted (maybe some "helpful" program edited them), or if they're replaced with garbage... if the filesystem were damaged it could've lost the contents of the files